# Best way to pass widgets to child widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, state, redraw

I'm new to flutter but I have a widget that wraps a custom painter. I am trying to get it to work so I can supply a Widget to this child widget's constructor and then use that widget as the child of the custom painter.

For example:

```
class MyPainterWrapper extends StatefulWidget {

  Widget _childWidget;

  SceneRender([this._childWidget]);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyPainterWrapperState(_childWidget);
  }
}

class MyPainterWrapperState extends State<SceneRender> {
Widget _childWidget;

MyPainterWrapperState(this._childWidget);

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
          CustomPaint(painter: MyPainter(), child: _childWidget)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And in another widget (called testWidget):

```
  bool _answerCorrect = false;
  bool _answerInputted = false;
  var _msgController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _answerFieldFocus = new FocusNode();
  DictionaryEntry _currentEntry;

void _checkIfCorrect(String answerGiven) {
    setState(() {
      _answerCorrect = false;
      if (_currentEntry.Full_Word == answerGiven)
        _answerCorrect = true;
      else if (_currentEntry.dictReadings.isNotEmpty) {
        for (AlternateDictionaryEntryReading entryReading in _currentEntry
            .dictReadings) {
          if (entryReading.Alternate_Reading == answerGiven) {
            _answerCorrect = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      _answerInputted = true;
      _msgController.clear();
    });

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      body: MyPainterWrapper(Center(Container(Column(children: <Widget>[
              if (_answerCorrect && _answerInputted) Text('CORRECT!'),
              if (!_answerCorrect && _answerInputted) Text('WRONG:'),
              if (_answerInputted)
                  Text(_currentEntry.Full_Word),
              if (_answerInputted)
                  for(AlternateDictionaryEntryReading reading in _currentEntry.dictReadings)
                    Text(reading.Alternate_Reading),
              Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 1000
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    for (DictionaryTranslation translation in _currentEntry.dictTranslations)
                      Text(translation.Translation),
                  ],
                )
                ),
              ),
              Text('Enter Answer:',),
              TextField(
                controller: _msgController,
                focusNode: _answerFieldFocus,
                onSubmitted: (String value) {
                  _checkIfCorrect(value);
                  _answerFieldFocus.requestFocus();
                },
              )
```

This works to render the first time correctly, but any `setState` calls from checkIfCorrect from testWidget do not force the child widget to rebuild. I've tried testing it this way and it works, so that leads me to believe that I'm passing the widget incorrectly to have it redrawn via setState

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      body: CustomPaint(painter: TestPainter(), child: Center(
          child: Container(...))
```

Comment: Could you show your call to `setState`? Just so it is a bit more clear what changes you are trying to make that don't work?

Comment: @h8moss I've added in some more detail of what my code actually looks like. Hopefully that'll help. The idea behind the page is have a textbox on top of a custom painter where users enter answers to questions and an animation plays on the painter when they get it right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your **MyPainterWrapperState** class reads like you are creating a new *_childWidget* property inside your state (which has a default value of null). You are then using it to initialize a new instance of MyPainterWrapperState, then throwing away the instance of MyPainterWrapper() that you just created.

You're not actually using the stateful part of your stateful widget at all; You're just calling a method that returns something once.

That said, your approach is basically right, but the implementation is off a little.

**My advice:**

First, you can use named properties to supply constructor arguments to your class. I've made that change in the code snippet shown below.

The **State** class of a stateful widget supplies a *widget* property that should be used to reference the properties of the widget that created it. The **State** widget should also have a solitary initializer that accepts no arguments.

Also good to know is that the **State** class provides an *initState*() method that you can override to initialize any class local variables that you declare. This should be used to give a value to your *_childWidget* property.

Finally, anything you expect to be rebuilt should be inside the **MyPainterWrapperState**() class. Your **SceneRender**() method doesn't appear in your code, but you might want to move it into MyPainterWrapperState() if you expect the scene to change based on the value of the child.

I suggest these changes.

- Pass arguments to **MyPainterWrapper** via named arguments.
- Remove the argument to **MyPainterWrapperState**() and reference the child through the *widget* property supplied to the state.
- Initialize *_childWidget* by overriding **initState**()
- If **SceneRender**() does anything that depends on the value of *_childWidget*, move it to the *build*() method of **MyPainterWrapperState**().

The Flutter docs are great, and the Flutter team has created a ton of helpful YouTube videos that explain in a couple of minutes examples of how to use dozens of them. For a better understanding of StatefulWidget, you can read about it [here.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

If you make these changes, your solution would look something like the code snippet below.

Presuming you make those changes, you would alter your call to MyPainterWrapper() to use named properties.

Change this line

```
 body: MyPainterWrapper(Center(Container(Column(children: <Widget>[
```

To this

```
 body: MyPainterWrapper(child: Center(Container(Column(children: <Widget>[
```

This won't get you to *done*, but it will get you closer. I also haven't run this through a compiler, so there are probably errors in the snippet, but this should serve to illustrate the approach.

````
class MyPainterWrapper extends StatefulWidget {

  MyPainterWrapper(
    { 
      @required child: this.childWidget,
    }
  );
  final Widget childWidget;

  // Not sure what this does, but I'm pretty sure that it doesn't
  // provide anything into the widget tree.
  // If it mutates its arguments, then you might still need it.
  // SceneRender([this._childWidget]);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // Note no arguments.
    return new MyPainterWrapperState();
  }
}

class MyPainterWrapperState extends State<MyPainterWrapper> {

// This is an uninitialized variable inside this class.
Widget _childWidget;

// MyPainterWrapperState(this._childWidget);

// Initialize state variables here.
@override initState() {
  // Assigns the widget class initializer to your state variable.
  _childWidget = widget.childWidget;
}


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
          CustomPaint(painter: MyPainter(), child: _childWidget)
      ],
    );
  }
}```
````